# How to set index.php as default page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I think after I put the code to remove the .php from URL, the index.php is not working anymore. Here is my .htaccess.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So, when I try to access some URL like: example.com/x/ does not work, but example.com/x/index/ works.

Comment: Could it be that it's looking for `mydomain.com/something.php`? Can you add a / to the end of `something`

Comment: Actually, on the folder something there is a file called index.php. So, I want the user access the mydomain.com/something/ and it works.

Comment: Okay. mydomain.com/something (no end / ) was the URL you first posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but try to use this as reference to your configuration. This has been taken from server that hosts my wordpress page (.htaccess file).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well, that works for the index.php part, but if I want to access for example mydomain.com/something/file I need to put .php on the final: mydomain.com/something/file.php but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. So, the index from something folder doesnt work. Like this mydomain.com/something does not work, but mydomain.com/something/index works.